# Laravel Relations many to many

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Probably a stupid mistake but I'm learning.
I tried create system message and i have problems because I have relations many to many mesages with ussers
Models Users:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;


    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function items(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Item');
    }

    public function messages(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }
}
```

Model Message:

```
class Message extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'id_user_to_send',
        'id_user_from',
        'text',
        'title'
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

Function in MessagesController

```
 public function mymessages()
{

    $user= Auth::user()->id;
    $messages = Message::latest()->where('id_user_to_send',$user)->orWhere('id_user_from',$user)->get();
    return view('messages.inbox', compact('messages', 'user'));
}
```

View:

```
    @foreach( $messages as $message)
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ $message->user->name }}</td><td>{{ $message->title }}
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Przeczytaj</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

And error :/

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'wymiana2.message_user' doesn't exist (SQL: select users.*,
>   message_user.message_id as pivot_message_id,
>   message_user.user_id as pivot_user_id from users inner join
>   message_user on users.id = message_user.user_id where
>   message_user.message_id = 4) (View:
>   C:\wymiana2\resources\views\messages\inbox.blade.php)

```
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('id_user_to_send')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('id_user_from')->unsigned();
    $table->string('text');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->foreign('id_user_to_send')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->foreign('id_user_from')->references('id')->on('users');
    $table->timestamps();
});

   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('email')->unique();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();


});
```

I read the documentation and tried many things. 
What am I doing wrong? Can you help me? give a hint?
I would like to display only the username, 
I could use the query but I still need to fix this relationship.

When i have:
User.php

`public function messages(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Message');
    }`

Message.php

```
     public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I have error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: C:\wymiana2\resources\views\messages\inbox.blade.php)

Comment: do you have a migration for `message_user` ?

Comment: No, i have users and messages. I dont now when i have this query with message_user

Comment: show us your migrations files, with screenshots

Comment: [many to many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Many to many relation expects an intermediate table(if you have one, then the name should be `message_user`(or specify it)), and the `messages` relation on `users` should be `belongstomany`

Comment: ok, i dont have a intermediate table. How should the intermediate table look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

As the messages are only to specific users, the **many to many relation won't be needed**. With keeping your database structure(no need for intermediate table), add the following relation to the `Message` model.

Message.php

```
class Message extends Model
{
    public function sender()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'id_user_from');
        }

    public function reciepient()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'id', 'id_user_to_send');
        }
}
```

User.php

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
    }
}
```

In your controller or view you can access the messages of the user with, `$user->messages();`

Sending user of the message with `$message->sender;` and the recipient user with `$user->reciepient;`

Comment: Ok, but this is good when user sent message to many users, but user send message to one user. I have problem with relations because i have in message "id_user_to_send" and "id_user_from".

Comment: @Peter, Answer updated. The previous answer was based on your error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `new` migration for your `pivot` table:

```
Schema::create('message_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->bigInteger('message_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
});
```